# Easy Shell Eclipse plugin randomly disappears

Tags: eclipse

I have the [Easy Shell](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/easyshell) plugin installed which adds an "Easy Shell" item to the right-click menu. However, it seems to periodically disappear between Eclipse restarts. At first it was at the top of the menu, then at the bottom and now it's gone completely. How do I fix this?